# update google cloud sql instance type

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I tried to update my google cloud sql instance from type "db-g1-small" to type "db-n1-standard-1"

But there has been more than 1h that it keeps in status "MAINTENANCE". And I found in the operations log: "An unknown error occurred." for this update.

I can't restart, neither edit this instance. In fact, I can't do any operation for this instance now. I have no idea what to do about this issue, someone can help, please, thanks!

Comment: after waiting 1 night, the status become running. It takes really long the update of intance type...

Comment: Is it still under "MAINTENANCE" status now?

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issue several times. Our case is that instance become high load with some reason, and does not fall down. Then we could not do anything including instance restart.

I don't know why this happen, but I think small instance may tend to happen this issue. We were using `db-n1-standard-2`, we faced this issue several times. Now we are using `db-n1-highmem-2`, since then we do not face this issue.

Or you can subscribe Google Support [from here](https://cloud.google.com/support/). You can contact Google directly with silver or higher support, and ask Google to restart instance if this issue happens again.

Comment: thanks for your response. I agree with you. Because when I tried to change to 1 instance higher (small to standard), I waited more than 12h... Then I tried to change 1 instance from standard to small, it finished really rapide!  less than ~5mins